# How to sync background color of ListboxItem(s) based on ViewModel value?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a ListBox bound to a list in ViewModel. I would like to "pin" certain ListBoxItems with different background color based on ViewModel. 
My view model looks like this, I want to highlight all the PinnedTasks in the ListBox. Seems like TypeConverter is the best way to go, Are there any other approaches?

```
 class ViewModel
 {
     public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }// Bound to ListBox
     public List<Task> PinnedTasks { get; set; } //These tasks are copy of Tasks, 
    //should be highlighted in ListBox
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can somehow modify the Tasks class to add a Pinned property or, alternatively, create a ViewModel for the Task class that contains a Pinned property, then you should be able to accomplish this with a DataTrigger when Styling/Templating your tasks.

Comment: I thought about that, but little hesitant to change my DTO for a View, I think, this is a better approach since it provides separation and cleaner code.

Comment: So then use what I said was the alternative - create a ViewModel for your Tasks object. That maintains the separation and will still give you much cleaner (and clearer) code than trying to do something with the two Lists, in my opinion.